# Cannot check level before the timer of the bot's leveling message per min clock hits exactly the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am completely new to javascript and haven't learned any kind of basics. However, I did learn to do some codes.

I have made a leveling bot that will send the users exp points for their message once per 40 seconds. But the command which they will check their level stats with is an embed that has gotten into that time. Now users have to wait for like 40 seconds to activate that command or even if they haven't, if they have typed something over 40 seconds ago, they can't activate the command unless another 40 seconds have passed.

```js
if (message.guild.id in stats === false) {
 stats[message.guild.id] = {};
}

const guildStats = stats[message.guild.id];
if (message.author.id in guildStats === false) {
 guildStats[message.author.id] = {
  xp: 0,
  level: 0,
  last_message: 0,
 };
}

const userStats = guildStats[message.author.id];
userStats.xp += random1.int(80, 100);
if (Date.now() - userStats.last_message > 40000) {
 userStats.last_message = Date.now();

 const rankS = '745901272506302484';
 const rankA = '744810702845378680';
 const rankB = '744835558991200367';
 const rankC = '750739926286336081';
 const rankD = '744810818771615745';
 const rankE = '744810822982959106';
 const rankF = '744810963558989844';

 const xpToNextLevel =
  5 * Math.pow(userStats.level, 1) + 100 * userStats.level + 100;
 if (userStats.xp >= xpToNextLevel) {
  userStats.level++;

  if (userStats.level >= 35) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankS);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 25) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankA);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 15) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankB);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 10) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankC);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 7) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankD);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 5) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankE);
  }
  if (userStats.level >= 1) {
   message.member.roles.add(rankF);
  }

  const Embed5 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setAuthor(
    message.author.username + '️' + userStats.level,
    message.author.displayAvatarURL()
   )
   .setDescription('You just leveled up to ' + userStats.level)
   .addField(
    'Keep up the work',
    'Text/VC/Post stuff in the server to gain more XP.'
   )
   .setColor(0xff5733)
   .setFooter('Type Ahri level to check you level card.');

  userStats.xp = userStats.xp - xpToNextLevel;
  client.channels.cache.get('743135573530902701').send(Embed5);
 }

 const args1 = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
 const command1 = args1.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (command1 === 'level') {
  const Embed6 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setAuthor(
    'Level card for ' + message.author.username,
    message.author.displayAvatarURL()
   )
   .addField('Current level ', userStats.level, true)
   .addField('Current exp ', userStats.xp, true)
   .addField('Exp needed for next level ', xpToNextLevel)
   .setColor(0xff5733);

  userStats.xp = userStats.xp - xpToNextLevel;
  client.channels.cache.get('743135573530902701').send(Embed6);

  jsonfile.writeFileSync('stats.json', stats);

  console.log(message.author.username + ' now has ' + userStats.xp);
  console.log(xpToNextLevel + ' XP needed for next level.');
 }
}
```

The main problem is I have to pull that (Embed6) out from this 2 brackets from the end. But I can't. One I pull it out, it can't connects it's objects to the consts that are inside the brackets.

Comment: As someone who started `discord.js` *before* learning JavaScript or any basic coding fundamentals, I **highly** suggest you hold off on this before learning the basics of JS.

Comment: @Lioness100 ok thanks. Then I will begin learning JS first and it's basics before doing any of the work with discord.js

Comment: @assassignshay cool! Obviously you can learn whatever however you want, it was just a recommendation. Good luck!